# JSONObject inside JSONArray building issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I need to give a JSONArray with a JSONObject to a JavaScript function that will pass these parameters to Java.

What I tried so far, that did NOT work:

//wrong syntax

```
var array = [[1, 1, "DescPDV1"]];
```

//right sintax, but works only as JSONArray, not JSONObject inside JSONArray

```
var array = [1, 1, "DescPDV1"];
```

//worng syntax

```
var array = [{1, 1, "DescPDV1"}];
```

//wrong syntax

```
var array = {1, 1, "DescPDV1"};
```

//wrong syntax

```
var array = {{1, 1, "DescPDV1"}};
```

My JSONObject is full of values, but no key addressed to them, then, no ["id" : "1", "blah" : "2"]... just the values [1, ""blah"].

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSONObject does not have keys, then it is not an object. You need to represent it as an array of arrays like this:

```
[[1, 1, "DescPDV1"]]
```

This is a valid JSON string, as can be confirmed at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)

Also, this is valid Javascript:

```
var array = [[1, 1, "DescPDV1"]];
```

As can be confirmed [here at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwRbY/)